# How do I set unique background images for react router components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'd like set to different background images for my 'Home' and 'About' components within the react project I'm building. I gave the 'Home' and 'About' components their own stylesheets (styles.css and about.css, respectively), then added a background-image: url() for each, but they both ended up with the 'Home' background.
Any suggestions on how to have different backgrounds for your components, when using react router?
Code as follows:

Home.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import './styles.css'
import hashi_logo_2 from './Photos/hashi_logo_2.png'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

function Home() {
    return (
        <div className = 'home'>
            <nav className = 'nav'>
                <ul>
                    <Link to = '/about' style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }} >
                    <li className='list'>About</li>
                    </Link>
                    <li className='list'>Food</li>
                    <li className='list'>Events</li>
                    <li className='list'>News</li>
                    <Link to ='/shop' style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }} >
                    <li className='list'>Shop</li>
                    </Link>
                    <li className='list'>Contact</li>
                    <li className='list'>Blog</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <main>
                <div class='main__image'>
                    <img src= {hashi_logo_2}/>
                </div>
            </main>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home
```

styles.css (styling for 'Home')

```
html * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    background-image: url('./Photos/hashi_pic_blurred_2.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    backdrop-filter: brightness(100%);
}

/* Navigation */

.nav {
    background-color:#8b0000;
    margin:0;
    padding: 15px 0;
    opacity: 0.75;
    position: fixed;
    width:100%;
}

ul {
    display:flex;
    list-style: none;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    font-size: 20px;
}


.list {
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white; 
    font-size: 25px; 
}

.list:hover{
    background-color: black;
}

/* Logo */

main {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 130px;
    padding-top:180px;
}

img {
    max-width: 40%;
    height: auto;
}
```

About.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import './about.css'

function About() {
    return(
        <div className = 'about'>
            <p>           
            Hashigo Zake takes the provision of fine beer to new levels.
            <br/>
            <br/>
            Seven days a week, 362 days a year, we serve the best that New Zealand's booming craft brewing industry has to offer.
            We are also building the best range of imported beer that New Zealand has seen. 
            <br/>
            We deal directly with breweries in Australia, Japan and the US and import many of the best beers in the Pacific rim. 
            <br/>
            We also have access to some of the best beers coming from Europe.
            <br/>
            <br/>
            We open at midday every day.
            <br/>
            Our location is 25 Taranaki St, Te Aro, Wellington, New Zealand.
            </p>
            <h2>"And he dreamed, and behold a ladder set up on the earth, and the top of it reached to heaven."</h2>
        </div>
    )
}

export default About
```

about.css

```
.about {
    height:100%;
    background-image: url('./Photos/hashi_taps.jpg');
}
p {
    margin-top: 50px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    /* background-color: rgb(139,0,0, 0.75); */
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    transform: translateY(20%);
    font-weight: bold;
}

h2 {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 400px;
    transform: translateY(-450%);
}
```

```
import React from 'react';
import Home from './Home'
import About from './About'
import Shop from './Shop'
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom'

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
    <div>
      <Switch>
      <Route path ='/' exact component = {Home}/>
      <Route path = '/about'  component = {About}/>
      <Route path = '/shop'  component = {Shop}/>
      </Switch>
    </div>
    </Router>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What does your router config look like?

Comment: ``` import React from 'react';
import Home from './Home'
import About from './About'
import Shop from './Shop'
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom'

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
    <div>
      <Switch>
      <Route path ='/' exact component = {Home}/>
      <Route path = '/about'  component = {About}/>
      <Route path = '/shop'  component = {Shop}/>
      </Switch>
    </div>
    </Router>
  )
}

export default App;   ```

Comment: argh sorry, that didn't work. I'll just add it to the original post

Comment: In home, you set the background `body` while in about you set the background on the component div container so it doesn't **override** the rule. This might cause an issue. If you can create a codesandbox that reproducing the issue, it will be easier to make sure.